# Something is wrong with my CSS Transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

Here is the example code: [Linky](http://jsbin.com/oraney/4/edit)

What I want to do is transition the color, background, and opacity. I works if i do:

```
transition: all .3s ease-in;
```

However when I try to do them individually none of them work. I'm thinking it's syntax but I've already spent too long figuring it out, I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working. You have no transition values set for the hover state. But the elements all transition on MouseOut. Add transitions for the hover state if you want transitions there.

Unlike a lot of CSS, transitions require you to put the properties in both states, there's no inheriting of transitions.

[All I added was a transition for the hover....](http://jsbin.com/oraney/5/edit)

Comment: You're suggesting I move the transitions from the `a` to the hover state for the anchor?

Comment: I added the following and it appears to give me what I'm looking for... `-webkit-transition-property: color, opacity; -webkit-transition-duration: .5s, 1s;`

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I was unclear. You need transition properties in both the link state and the hover state to transition between the two. Basically, transition properties mean "transition from whatever it is now to (this)" if you don't have a transition property, then the browser doesn't know you want to transition.